# microsoft access vba multi-select listbox insert query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm creating a form in Microsoft Access 2010 to upload to a SharePoint website (first time doing this). I have a form with a command button I want to do two things with, insert all the single value items into one table and insert all the selections in the list box into a separate table.

The problem I'm having is that when I put the "DoCmd.OpenQuery 'Add Goal'" at the top, it adds the single value items perfectly, but when I put it at the bottom, the code doesn't do anything. In either case the list box items do not get added to the second table. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAddGoal_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmdAddGoal_Click_Err

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim vItem As Variant

    If IsNull(lstIndAcc) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Me.lstIndAcc
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSQL = "INSERT INTO Individuals_Accountable (Goal_ID, Employee_ID)" _
                & "SELECT Goal_ID, Employee_ID FROM Goal, Employee WHERE Goal.Activites_And_Milestones = [Forms]![Add Goal]![txtActivities] AND" _
                & "Employee.Employee_Name = " & vItem
            End If
            DoCmd.OpenQuery strSQL
        Next
    End With
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Add Goal"

    cmdAddGoal_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

    cmdAddGoal_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdAddGoal_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: I am surprised the SQL does anything. The SQL should fail because need a space to separate AND from Employee.Employee_Name: `AND "`. Also, if Employee_Name is text field, should need apostrophe delimiters: `='" & vItem & "'"`

Comment: My apologies for not clarifying, the SQL inside the for loop does not work (at least I'm not sure yet). The "Add Goal" query works when I put it before the declaration of variables but not if I put it at the end as shown above. I've made the changes you suggested, but when I press the command button nothing happens.

Comment: Why do you open query object anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should have looked more closely at the code before commenting.

OpenQuery is used to open a query object, not run an SQL statement constructed in VBA.

Use `DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL` or I prefer `CurrentDb.Execute strSQL`

The first will generate warning popups unless you also have code to disable warnings.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: It worked! Had to do some basic debugging after but managed to figure it out. Thank you!